# Grails 3.0.x - how to increase heap space when using "grails run-app"

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

When executing "grails run-app" from the command line for a Grails 3.0.1 web application, I always get a maximum heap size of 768M, which seems to be the hardcoded default in the Grails Gradle plugin.

The settings in JAVA_OPTS or GRAILS_OPTS are not respected.

How can I let run-app use more heap space? Something to set in application.yaml or build.gradle?

Answer (score 13):

This seems to do the trick in build.gradle:

```
bootRun {
    jvmArgs = ['-Xmx2048m']
}
```